# Cannot connect to local webserver in app, but adb shell works

Tags: java, android, adb, android-source

I have a system service on my android phone which runs a webserver as soon as the device is booted. When I go into the adb shell and use curl to make a request it works perfectly fine, but as soon as I try to do it within any android app running on the same device I get an error saying that it failed to connect:

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 8545) from /127.0.0.1 (port 48102) after 10000ms
```

and this is for reference my curl command (this works):

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8545
```

Comment: usesClearTextTraffic.

Comment: @blackapps not the error. Had that at first, but added it to the manifest already

Comment: What happens when you enter the URL in a web browser like Chrome on the device? What Android version is running?

Comment: @Robert From the browser I can open the site. I am running Android 11, or more specifically LineageOS 19.1

Comment: try to run an `adb reverse tcp:8545 tcp:8080` or `adb reverse tcp:8080 tcp:8545`

Comment: @WilsonCastiblanco What is the reason behind the command? I am trying to get to a webserver that is being run on the same device as the app

Comment: `adb reverse ` enable a port in your phone to be accessed by your computer, but if you are trying to run it on the same phone, try `adb reverse tcp:8545 tcp:8545` or in your android phone, use `10.0.2.2` instead of `localhost` or `0.0.0.0`

Comment: @WilsonCastiblanco `10.0.2.2` only works for the Android emulator no for real devices.

Comment: `From the browser I can open the site.` Ok. But that does not match your complaint: `but as soon as I try to do it within any android app running on the same device I get an error`

Comment: And it is time you show your code as we have no idea what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

WebView honors **clear text traffic** for applications targeting API level 26 and higher.

The application you are using to access your service (which you didn't mention) should have the attribute `android:usesCleartextTraffic` set to `true`.